# PHP User class security assistance?

Tags: php, class, session

I am new to class development in PHP, however I am still quite confused by the concept of sessions.

Question 1: Can sessions be changed by client manipulations? If not can I set static sessions and use them without validation?

Question 2: How should I be managing my user accounts?

I do use SALT however, a code is generated during registration and inserted into DB where it's used for login reference. Any corrections with explanation would be much appreciated, as well anything about sessions being modified by client.

```
class user {
    private $username   = '';   
    private $password   = '';
    private $salt       = '';
    public  $prefix     = 'rhs_';

    function __construct () {
        $this->username = '';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->salt     = '';

        session_start();
    }

    public function login ($username, $password) {
        $mysql_conn = Database::obtain();
        $username = $mysql_conn->escape($username);
        $sql = 'SELECT `password`, `salt`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `permission` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`="'.$username.'"';
        $row = $mysql_conn->query_first($sql);

        if(!empty($row['password'])) {
            $encrypted = md5(md5($mysql_conn->escape($password)).$row['salt']);
            if ($encrypted == $row['password']) {
                $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'username']     = $username;
                $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'password']     = $password;
                $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'name']         = $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];
                $_SESSION[$this->prefix.'permission']   = $row['permission'];
                header('location: ?page=cpanel');
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sessions are unrelated to classes. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to class development in PHP

Even if you are experienced programmer making an unsafe authentication system is easy as pie. You should be using OpenID(or systems like that like for example facebook connect) instead. They have  security-experts as employees. I created a [little library you can use for this](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-openid). You can see a demo at http://westerveld.name/php-openid//

> Can sessions be changed by client
>   manipulations? If not can I set static
>   sessions and use them without
>   validation?

It can not be changed by clients, but a users session could be stolen by hackers. You need to prevent [session-fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) =>  [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

> How should I be managing my user
>   accounts?

You probably should not do this, because the change you make a mistake is BIG. But below are some quick tips:

- You should use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to store your password in the database. Because **I did notice you are not using [key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_strengthening)**. You should perform a benchmark, and if you can generate hashes quickly, then you are definitely not securing your passwords safely. Bcrypt is a very good for hashing(used by phpass. You should use that library), because it is Moore's law proof.
- Protect your users against [CSRF](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries).
- You should read [the OWASP top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

I also have created a little [authentication library](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-auth) just for the fun of it. And I think it is pretty safe although for example `logout.php` is still vulnerable to [CSRF](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) although this is not really a big problem(and the fix is very easy).

Comment: The website was developed to allow users to gain access via login then make adjustments to the server by adding queries (secured). The queries are all handled correctly and escaped, and if necessary sanitized of any exploits.

Comment: The only thing that worries me at this point is that, I am not re-validating the session permission, which I feel can open doors to exploits where users can get into CPanel and make the adjustments.

Should I be doing MySQL retrieval and comparing with the sessions to confirm they are proper upon page load?

Comment: Also, it's impossible for a user to cross-site with my forms, since they are handled server-side which means it will not do anything unless submitted by client on site and it has been validated by server.

Comment: prevent session fixation(session_regenerate_id), sql-injections(PDO) and XSS-holes(input filtering), make cookies http-only for extra security and you are good to go! The sessions are on your server and can not be altered, but can be stolen if you  have session fixation.   Also use phpass to store your passwords!!!

Answer (score 3):

A session is a file on your server where variables can be written and saved. Each session file corresponds to one active visitor to your site. PHP automatically deletes files that haven't been read from or written to for ~24 minutes.

Sessions are linked to users by a cookie. When a user browses to your page where you use sessions, PHP checks to see if a specially named cookie was sent with the request, containing their session identifier.

- If the cookie exists, that identifier tells PHP which session file to open and read to populate `$_SESSION`.
- If no cookie exists, a new identifier is generated and sent as a cookie to the user, and a new empty session file is created.

Since the sessions are files on your server, your users cannot modify them.

Comment: Does that mean I would need to update the sessions or they will become inactive? If so, wouldn't calling the sessions renew them?

Comment: When a visitor hits a page of your site where you call `session_start()`, the session file is read. That resets the expiration on the file. You don't have to write any special code.

Comment: Can that data at anytime be changed by a user or is it fine being left static?

Comment: A user can no more edit files on your server than **I** can edit files on **your** home computer. They can't.